# How do you call a function of a base class inside a derived class with same function names

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I am trying to call a function in a derived class with the same name existing in the base class. The function simply prints class elements.
For example:

```
class A                             // Base Class
{                                    
public:                          
     string a;
     int b;

     A(){};                         //Default Constructor                         
     A(string x,int y):a(x),b(y){}  //Parametrized Constructor
     ~A(){};                        //Destructor
     void printInfo()
     {
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
     };     
};

class B:public A                    // Derived Class
{                                    
public:                          
     string c;


     B(){};                         //Default Constructor                         
     B(string z):c(z){}             //Parametrized Constructor
     ~B(){};                        //Destructor
     void printInfo()
     {
        cout << a << endl;
        //I am trying to call printInfo of A inside this function
     }; 
};
```

So that in the output, when I create an object of `B` (let's say `B example;`) and try to use `printInfo()` member function of class B (Ex: `example.printInfo();`), I would print first c and then a and b. Also it will not be limited with 2 classes, but more than 5 classes having a common `printInfo()` member function. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Your `printInfo` will need a return type. Then you just do `A::printInfo()`…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Sorry not to mention the type of my member function. It is a ```void``` function, so it doesn't return anything. I uptaded the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> //I am trying to call printInfo of A inside this function

```
class B:public A                    // Derived Class
{                                    
public:                          
     string c;


     B(){};                         //Default Constructor                         
     B(string z):c(z){}             //Parametrized Constructor
     ~B(){};                        //Destructor
     printInfo()
     {
        cout << a << endl;
        A::printInfo();  //<-- call base class version
     }; 
};
```